# Find content of one file from another set of gz files in UNIX

Tags: file, grep

I have a list of 500 ids in search_these.txt file; and 300 gzipped data files numbered like *{}_of_300_search_in.gz*. I want to extract data for 500 ids from each of 300 data files into one output file.

I have tried the following code but it throws an error `Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...`. I'm  not sure what am I doing wrong here.

```
cat search_these.txt | while read line
do
    seq 1 300 | xargs -I '{}' bash -c 'zcat {}_of_300_search_in.gz | grep -w $line' >> output.txt
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `grep -w -- "$line"` to avoid `$line` being interpreted as options and arguments. The `--` ends the option list, which is necessary when `$line` starts with a leading `-`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, you can reduce your entire code by the following single command:

```
zgrep -hf search_these.txt {1..300}_of_300_search_in.gz
```

The command `zgrep` is a simple wrapper, similar to `zcat`, that `gunzip`'s the file and passes it and all accompanying arguments to `grep`. So the arguments `-h` and `-f` can be read from `man grep` to understand what they do.